# Swiftui navigationBarTitle beging overwritten with Preview View Text

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar

When I go to my second page which has a ScrollView, and I scroll to the point it becomes inline and then return to the mainView - the navigationBarTitles is being overwritten with both navigationBarTitles.

I am using Xcode Version 12.5 (12E262) and this is iOS 14.

It is happening both in the simulator and on a device.

MainView

[image]

ScrollView

[image]

ScrollView scrolled so it becomes inline

[image]

And when I return to the MainView from the inline NavBar I get this.

[image]

It is fine - unless I have scrolled.  And what makes it even more confusing it only does it about 25% of the time.

I am just using "self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()" to return to the mainView

I am using a NavigationLink to go to the second page.

```
NavigationLink(destination: ScrollView(), isActive: $showScroll ) { EmptyView() }
```

Is there something I have missed when dismissing from Scrolling?

very plain code for the scrollView.

I am obviously missing something or this is a big issue with SwiftUI and Xcode.

Thank you.

```
var body: some View {
     
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
             
        }
         
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitle("scrollView Page")
        .navigationBarItems(
            
            leading:
                
                Button(action:{ 
                   self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()},
                 label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                }) 
             
}
```

Comment: Provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Unless you have to target iOS 13, you may want to move away from the deprecated `navigationBarItems` and use the various `toolbar` APIs

Comment: interesting sugestion.  I will see if it makes any difference.  thanks.

Comment: it seems to be either a NavigationLink or my use of  UIScreen.main.bounds?  After removing them the issue went away.  No idea why they would create such an issue with a NavigationTitle?  thanks

Comment: `navigationBarTitle`and `navigationBarItems` are being deprecated use `navigationTitle` and/or `.toolbar` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbartitle(_:)-6p1k7

Comment: moving to .toolbar solved the issue.  thank you.